# Change the result of subtracting two columns in the pandas dataframe if we get a negative value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change value of `df['points']` to 0 if subtraction gives negative values

`df['points'] = df['HOME_SCORE'] - df['prev_HOME_SCORE']`

I tried

`df['points'].apply(lambda x: (df['HOME_SCORE'][x] - df['prev_HOME_SCORE'][x]) if (df['HOME_SCORE'][x] - df['prev_HOME_SCORE'][x]) >= 0 else 0`
but don't know how to get index of x and also don't know if it possible with this approach

Comment: use np.where, or clip

Comment: `(df['HOME_SCORE'] - df['prev_HOME_SCORE']).clip(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `clip`

```
df['points'] = (df['HOME_SCORE'] - df['prev_HOME_SCORE']).clip(0)
```

or `np.where`:

```
df['points'] = np.where((df['HOME_SCORE'] - df['prev_HOME_SCORE']) < 0, 0,df['HOME_SCORE'] - df['prev_HOME_SCORE'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

df['points'] = np.where((df['HOME_SCORE'] - df['prev_HOME_SCORE']) < 0, 0,(df['HOME_SCORE'] - df['prev_HOME_SCORE']))
```

will make the points 0 if the answer would be negative otherwise it's the answer.

Comment: doesn't it need a bracket for the subtraction?